# Play an audio with corresponding sequence of images being animated w/ play & pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to create an animation of series of images with background audio using HTML5 and javascript maybe ajax or jquery. I'm basically trying to make an animation of a simple conversation between several people (portrayed by images) and speech through (audio).

I have an audio file (mp3/ogg) and a series of images. When I play the audio, the sequence of images will be displayed accordingly.

Here's the catch, If I pause or replay the audio, sequence of image must also stop or replay from the start.

So the sequence of images must be in sync with the audio playing.

Any ideas or concepts? Right now I have a working jPlayer with play/pause. Also can it be done with jPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

Just make your decisions based on the `currentTime` of your audio. [Example](http://jsbin.com/ajihuh/2/)

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio'),
    img = document.querySelector('img'),
    imgs = ['http://raptorsrepublic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/meh_cat.jpg', 'http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_8tZf9lm-smo/R7hn7pNx-jI/AAAAAAAAALI/86DN7VedT_Q/s400/meh.jpg', 'http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-yWsoWNVX4jU/UAy5uJxD52I/AAAAAAAANSc/OTje6k_C5Q8/s1600/meh2.jpg'],
    duration, interval, currentImg;

(function callee(ready) {

    if (ready !== false) ready = true;

    if (!ready) {
        return audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', callee);
    }

    if (!audio.playing) audio.play();

    if (!duration) {
        duration = audio.duration;
        interval = duration / imgs.length;
    }

    if (isNaN(duration)) return setTimeout(callee, 1000); 

    var currentTime = audio.currentTime;

    if (!currentImg) {
        img.src = currentImg = imgs[0];
    }

    var currentTimeImage = imgs[Math.floor(currentTime / interval)];

    if (currentTimeImage != currentImg) {
        img.src = currentImg = currentTimeImage;
    }

    setTimeout(callee, 1000);

})(false);
```